# How exception handling mechanishm really works in .net?

Tags: .net, exception

I wonder, How exception handling mechanishm actualy works in .net?

Just want to know, what happens in runtime internally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally the CLR uses the Structured Exception Handling of Windows. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657(VS.85).aspx for more details.

You may also find the description in CLR via C# by Jeffrey Ricther useful.